# What does Dropbox use for Revision History? How can I add my own?

Tags: php

One of the neater features of Dropbox is that it keeps previous versions of the files you upload.

Part of our site is a similar file repository (customers upload their files to store them offsite), and we'd like to implement a similar feature.

How does Dropbox manage revisions? Do they use some off the shelve revision software that autocommits each file? Or did they just roll their own solution?

I'm hoping there's a 3rd party library I can use for this as it's not the sort of thing we have time to do from scratch ourselves.

Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 4):

More than likely they used a custom solution. Possible methods you can look at are storing a separate file on filesystem for each version, store a separate file in the database for each version, or calculate the diff for the revised file and store that.

The third option is the best as it uses the least space.

Take a look at [`xdiff_file_bdiff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-bdiff.php), it calculates a binary diff of two files (The old version and the new version). The xdiff library should give you the tools you need to do this. You could also look at using something like git for version control, just automate the process using PHP. You'd probably want to run some benchmarks to see what solution works the fastest.

Comment: My understanding is that the technologies behind DropBox are kept fairly secret, but at the same time, they do admit that it's based on Open Source software, so you should be able to find ways to replicate all their functionality.

Comment: I didn't know about `xdiff_file_bdiff()`; neat. So would I store the initial version as-is, and just the deltas for each additional version? Or would I keep the latest version as the whole file and re-delta the past ones?

Comment: Yeah, any website like DropBox will keep their competitive advantage pretty tied down. I would image they are using a variation of some open source binary diff program however. Probably modified to minimize CPU usage and disk space.

Comment: @DOOManiac I'd store the original version, with each additional version as a diff. Then I'd also store the newest version as-is. The file patching operation is expensive, so you don't want to have to re-delta a bunch of files every time something is updated, and you also don't want to have to calculate the current file whenever it's requested.

Comment: @RogueCoder Thanks! Just to clarify, would the delta for each version be against the original version? Or would revision 3 be the delta from 2, which is the delta from 1; so you'd need to chain them together?